# Different spacing character and word spacing depending on browser

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, xhtml, epub

I have a problem with epubs (xhtml files) generated by InDesign epub export. They look OK in Firefox, but not in Chrome nor in MAC epub reader. 
In Chrome and epub reader, the spacing between some of the words is either increased or decreased compared to the same xhtml viewed in Firefox.

Consider the following div

```
 <div id="_idContainer039" class="Basic-Text-Frame">
  <div style="width:5270.4px;height:2592px;position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;-webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%; -webkit-transform: translate(0px,5.12px) rotate(0deg) scale(0.05);transform-origin: 0% 0%; transform: translate(0px,5.12px) rotate(0deg) scale(0.05);">
    <p class="body-text-25pt-no-indent ParaOverride-1">
      <span id="w79" class="CharOverride-17" style="position:absolute;top:1181px;left:1514.4px;letter-spacing:-6.17px;">für </span>
      <span id="w80" class="CharOverride-17" style="position:absolute;top:1181px;left:2029.29px;letter-spacing:2.34px;">Sofias </span>
      <span id="w81" class="CharOverride-17" style="position:absolute;top:1181px;left:2982.32px;letter-spacing:-17.54px;">Vater,</span>
      <span id="w82" class="CharOverride-18" style="position:absolute;top:1678.86px;left:549.45px;letter-spacing:4.63px;">Blumen</span>
      <span id="w83" class="CharOverride-17" style="position:absolute;top:1821px;left:2288.22px;letter-spacing:-6.17px;">für </span>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

and then the styles for it:

```
div.Basic-Text-Frame {
border-style:solid;
}

#_idContainer039 {
-webkit-transform:translate(21.600px,114.396px) rotate(0.000deg) skew(0.000deg) scale(1.000,1.000);
-webkit-transform-origin:0% 0%;
height:135.72px;
left:0px;
position:absolute;
top:0px;
transform:translate(21.600px,114.396px) rotate(0.000deg) skew(0.000deg) scale(1.000,1.000);
transform-origin:0% 0%;
width:263.52px;
}


span.CharOverride-17 {
color:#000000;
font-family:"TypographyofCoop-Forged", sans-serif;
font-size:380px;
font-style:normal;
font-weight:normal;
}

span.CharOverride-18 {
color:#a82478;
font-family:"Girard Sansusie", sans-serif;
font-size:540px;
font-style:normal;
font-weight:600;
}
```

I suppose it's something depending on -webkit-transform, but I don't know what. I need my files to be compatible with Chrome (and therefore, supposedly MAC as well). I am using latest Chrome, 47.0.2526.80 m.

Should I do some other transformations for this?

This is how it looks:

[image: Preview]

Thanks for the info!

Comment: If I put that in an xhtml file, it does look terrible, but it looks the same kind of terrible in both browsers. Maybe it's the font?

Comment: @MrLister - I don't think so, it happens with simple fonts as well... This is a very minor difference, though unaceptable from publishing point of view

Comment: Well, it looks like this on my computer: http://i.stack.imgur.com/83q4C.png and the differences between browsers aren't really notable.

Comment: @MrLister - I have uploaded a picture of preview indicating the issue. Indeed, in your case that's the font's issue, but I do have all the fonts. Also, weird that Chrome can handle font variants and ligatures worse than firefox.

Comment: The glyphs in the "Girard Sansusie" font are different on the two browsers. The spiral serif for the capital letters is not used on Chrome but it is used on Firefox, changing the length of the word. It may be possible to get Firefox to match Chrome by adjusting the CSS selector _font-variant-caps_